# Text doesnt show up when I share it to facebook (android studio)

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-studio, facebook-javascript-sdk

I didnt use the Facebook SDK. I use intend instead. I did the same thing for google+ and Twitter, they work well.However, when I click the bottom for sharing on facebook, the facebook's post page shows up but it didnt show the sharing text on the texing place. It supposes to show a line of text "Hello World.I am testing for my app on Facebook" on the posting place.

Here is my code

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent .setType("text/plain");

                intent .setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                intent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World.I am testing for my app on Facebook");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent );
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Facebook has not been installed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Facebook-v4, you can't share user intended data directly over users timeline.

Facebook have restricted it to do so. Here Facebook states, user should have full control on what they share.

Comment: No.. Even that will not solve your purpose .. After integrating SDK you can not compel user to post what you wish. Even then user will have full rights over what content is being shared over there Timeline.

Comment: One more point to mention.. In case you need to share App link or some other URL related stuff, then for sure go ahead with integrating Facebook SDK over gradle and there is class named some what Share...*** (Don't remember right now) , which will solve your purpose.